# Oracle index analyze stats - managed by whom?

Tags: oracle, index, oracle-12c

Some questions about managing indexes.

We saw in some cases where indexes weren't analyzed in weeks, even though data was inserted and queried from them - using conditions that use these indexes. The queries were very slow - probably because the index was broken.

Query to get the indexes (some had `last_analyzed` weeks old):

```
SELECT
    table_name, index_name, index_type, visibility, status, last_analyzed, dropped
FROM
    all_indexes;
```

In what cases do indexes stop being analyzed?

What's the way to get indexes analyzed automatically?

Do I still need to manage index analysis somehow manually if they break? How can they break? How do I know they are broken? How to fix? In what intervals?

Perhaps there's no auto-management? This would be very surprising. But if this is the case, how to manage indexes manually? Thanks.

Comment: Oracle administrator guide has an entire section about index maintenance. May be you could start there and come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: Oracle has a standard stats job that runs every day.  It is smart enough to know what segments (indexes, tables) are in need of having stats refreshed. I fear you are contracting a case of Compulsive Tuning Disorder.

Comment: Added some motivation regarding things we're seeing in production. @mustaccio, admin guide? This is crazy for Oracle to request users to fix stuff that's broken in their DB.

Comment: If an index were truly broken, you'd have much worse problems.  With the new information you've added, it may not be a case of CTD, but I think you are grasping at straws.  There are a gazillion reasons why a query may be slow, and 'broken indexes' is waaay down the list.  Instead of jumping to conclusions about "broken" indexes, step back and simply approach this as a performance issue.  It is most likely simply a sql that it not written in an optimal matter.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgdba/index.html

Comment: Ed, thanks. I'm quite sure it's not the sql as it works great if the index isn't stale.

Comment: There's a huge difference between 'stale statistics' and 'broken index'. It is quite possible, especially in a DW application, that the default rules used by the automatic stats collection are not optimal for a given situation.  In that case, as @Balazs Papp said, it is very normal to simply schedule your own stats collection job on the objects in question.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka If you are licensed for the Diagnostic Pack you can check whether the plan has changed. (I'm not a licensing expert at all so check you have the bill payer's permission.) If you have Cloud Control (previously Oracle Enterprise Manager or OEM) there are pointy-clicky options for that. If not, query `dba_hist_sqlstat` for the `sql_id` (subject to licensing) and see whether `plan_hash_value` has changed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the fact alone that some objects have old statistics, does not necessarily mean they need to be refreshed.

By default indexes (tables) are analyzed automatically.

[About Automatic Optimizer Statistics Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_stats.htm#TGSQL-GUID-E4EFD512-EAF9-4AF3-943F-FDEC7E47B23C)

> The automated maintenance tasks infrastructure (known as AutoTask)
> schedules tasks to run automatically in Oracle Scheduler windows known
> as maintenance windows.
>
> By default, one window is scheduled for each day of the week.
> Automatic optimizer statistics collection runs as part of AutoTask. By
> default, the collection runs in all predefined maintenance windows.
>
> To collect the optimizer statistics, the database calls an internal
> procedure that operates similarly to the GATHER_DATABASE_STATS
> procedure with the GATHER AUTO option. Automatic statistics collection
> honors all preferences set in the database.
>
> The principal difference between manual and automatic collection is
> that the latter prioritizes database objects that need statistics.
> Before the maintenance window closes, automatic collection assesses
> all objects and prioritizes objects that have no statistics or very
> old statistics.

In addition to the above ("*have no statistics or very old statistics*"):

[Determining When Optimizer Statistics Are Stale](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_stats.htm#TGSQL424)

To shortly summarize: the database tracks the number of modified rows in a table. When this number gets higher than a threshold, the statistics are considered stale, and the table is a candidate for gathering statistics.

The definition of this threshold:

[DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68594)

> `STALE_PERCENT` - This value determines the percentage of rows in a
> table that have to change before the statistics on that table are
> deemed stale and should be regathered. The valid domain for
> stale_percent is non-negative numbers. The default value is 10,
> meaning a table having more than 10% of changes is considered as
> stale.

```
SQL> select dbms_stats.get_prefs('STALE_PERCENT') from dual;

DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('STALE_PERCENT')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10
```

So objects statistics are considered stale whenever more than 10% of the rows changed since the last time statistics were collected on that object.

This 10% value may or may not be adequate for your tables. You can set this value manually even on a per-object basis, so statistics would be considered stale more frequently.

You also have the option of gathering statistics manually, even with a scheduled job.